# Reference to non-existent field when using variable for struct access

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

I'm very new to Matlab and maybe a very basic question, but I need help:

I have a path:

```
file = C:\this\is\path\to\my_file.mat
```

This is a file which contains nested structure and I need just to access  one variable. In my script, first I need to get the file name which I will use as variable later:

```
[pathstr,name,ext] = fileparts(file);
```

So, now I have the variable *name* with the content *my_file.mat*

```
S = load(file)

value = S.('name').structA.SubstructA1.variableA
```

Matlab is generating the message:

```
"Reference to non-existent field 'name'."
```

So, how is the correct way to use the variable in this case ?

Comment: Start with a blank workspace (using `clear`) then do `file = 'C\...'` and `load(file)`. Whatever variables you saved in `my_file.mat` will now be in your workspace, no assigning to new variables needed. Of course you don't always have to start with a blank workspace, but it makes this example clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, just remove the single quotes from around the variable, name, like this:

```
value = S.(name).structA.SubstructA1.variableA
```